# rsync remote files over SSH to my local machine, using sudo privileges on local side, and my personal SSH key

Tags: ssh, rsync

I want to sync a directory `/var/sites/example.net/` from a remote machine to a directory at the same path on my local machine.

The remote machine only authenticates SSH connections with keys, not passwords.

On my local machine I have an alias set up in ~/.ssh/config so that I can easily run `ssh myserver` to get in.

I'm trying `rsync -a myserver:/var/sites/example.net/ /var/sites/example.net/` but it fails because my local user does not have permission to edit the local directory /var/sites/example.net/.

If I try `sudo rsync -a myserver:/var/sites/example.net/ /var/sites/example.net/` (just adding sudo), I can fix the local permission issue, but then I encounter a different issue -- my local root user does not see the proper ssh key or ssh alias.

Is there a way I can accomplish this file sync by modifying this rsync command? I'd like to avoid changing anything else (e.g. no changes to file perms or ssh setup)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo rsync -e "sudo -u localuser ssh" -a myserver:/var/sites/example.net/ /var/sites/example.net/
```

This runs `rsync` as root, but the `-e` flag causes `rsync` to run `ssh` as your local user (using `sudo -u localuser`), so the `ssh` command has access to the necessary credentials.  Rsync itself is still running as root, so it has the necessary filesystem permissions.

Comment: How would one supply the sudo password to rsync when running in non-interactive mode, such as a crontab script?

Answer (score 6):

Just improving on top of [larsks's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21642228/167897):

```
sudo rsync -e "sudo -u $USER ssh" ...
```

So in your case change `rsync -a myserver:/var/sites/example.net/ /var/sites/example.net/` to `sudo rsync -e "sudo -u $USER ssh" -a myserver:/var/sites/example.net/ /var/sites/example.net/`.

Answer (score 2):

With regards to @larsks' answer, If you have your key loaded into the ssh agent, which is my use case, you can instead do:

```
sudo rsync -e "env SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK ssh" /source/path /destination/path
```

Instead of the double `sudo`.

My use case, if anyone is interested in replicating, is that I'm SSHing to a non-root sudo-er account on remote A, and need to rsync root-owned files between remote A and remote B. Authentication to both remotes is done using keys I have on my real local machine and I use `-A` to forward the ssh-agent authentication socket to remote A.

Answer (score 2):

[Guss's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59547579/275663) works well if you want to use `sudo rsync` for local file permissions but want to utilise your user's SSH session. However, it falls short when you also want to use your SSH config file.

You can follow [Wernight's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29652759/275663) by using `sudo` to switch the user for the SSH connection and supplying a path to the config file, but this won't work if you have to enter a passphrase. So, you can combine both approaches by making use of the `--preserve-env` flag:

```
sudo --preserve-env=SSH_AUTH_SOCK rsync -e "sudo --preserve-env=SSH_AUTH_SOCK -u $USER ssh" hostname:/source/path /destination/path
```

Note that it's necessary to cascade this flag through both `sudo` commands so it does look a bit messy!

Answer (score 0):

As requested by [Derek above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639906/rsync-remote-files-over-ssh-to-my-local-machine-using-sudo-privileges-on-local/21642228#comment57762319_21642228):

when sudo asks for a password then you need to modify the sudoers config with `sudo visudo` and add a entry with `NOPASSWD:` in front of the rsync command.

For details you could consult `man sudoers`.

this will work in every mode, even via cron, at, systemd.service+timer, etc.

test it with: `ssh <user>@<your-server> "sudo <your-rsync-command>"`