# How to mount remote ecryptfs directory?

Tags: ssh, rsync, ubuntu-server, ecryptfs

I use `rsync` to synchronize the data on my client with a decrypted ecryptfs-container on the server.

What I want to achieve is the following automatic process:

1. If, on the server, `keyctl show` already has my desired key signature go to (3.)
2. `ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek` to add my key to the keyring on the server
3. `mount -i /mnt/path/to/decrypted` to make sure the decrypted folder is mounted on the server
4. `rsync` from client to server
5. Optional: Unmount folder and remove key signature (not important here)

Currently, for steps 1,2,3 I use `ssh -tq ...` to execute the command and evaluate the result.

My problem is as follows: It seems like ecryptfs requires a persistent user session on the server. Otherwise, the key is added and instantly dropped because of user logout (`ssh -tq ...` ends after command completion).

I just recognized that `ssh -tq 'ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek; mount -i /mnt/path/to/decrypted'` apparently works as expected. The key is dropped again afterwards, but the mount succeeds. This implies I have to realize the "dynamic prompt" (step 1) on the server. Is this already the best solution or can I also realize this on the client?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a programming question? It appears to be off-topic; see SuperUser.

Comment: @MSalters maybe this is not exactly a pure programming question. But other questions concerning `rsync` and its applications (e.g. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639906/rsync-remote-files-over-ssh-to-my-local-machine-using-sudo-privileges-on-local?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639906/rsync-remote-files-over-ssh-to-my-local-machine-using-sudo-privileges-on-local?rq=1) or other `rsync` related questions) are here apparently accepted though. Keeping this in mind I would like to stay away from double-posting and try my luck here.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon your post several times today while trying to realize exactly what you were describing, but did not find any help. I finally managed to find a solution by myself.

This solution is to take advantage of the `--rsync-path` option of rsync. Here is an extract from the [man page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rsync1.html):

```
    --rsync-path=PROGRAM
          Use this to specify what program is to  be  run  on  the  remote
          machine  to start-up rsync.  Often used when rsync is not in the
          default      remote-shell’s      path       (e.g.       --rsync-
          path=/usr/local/bin/rsync).   Note  that PROGRAM is run with the
          help of a shell, so it can be any program,  script,  or  command
          sequence  you’d  care to run, so long as it does not corrupt the
          standard-in & standard-out that rsync is using to communicate.

          One tricky example is to set a different  default  directory  on
          the  remote  machine  for  use  with the --relative option.  For
          instance:

              rsync -avR --rsync-path="cd /a/b && rsync" hst:c/d /e/
```

The example given in the last paragraph of the manual gave me the idea to use this parameter to mount the ecryptfs directory.

And here is the code:

```
rsync --rsync-path="(printf \"%s\" \"$passphrase\" | ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek && ecryptfs-mount-private) &> /dev/null && rsync" -aKLv local_to_sync remotehost.com:~/Private/
```